# Steam OpenId authentication with angularjs and spring boot backend

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, openid

I'm a spring beginner, but for educational purposes I'm writing an app using AngularJS for frontend and springboot for backend. My app is connected with spring community and I want to add logging user with Steam. This is a place where I stucked and need advice, help or example. Can you provide me a quick 'how-to'?

Comment: Start here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19416154/openid-based-authentication-in-angular-js-with-flask-backend

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?